# Struct Initialization in constructor

Tags: c++

I am having trouble declaring a struct initialization in a constructor.

example:

```
struct Test
{
   int x;
   int y;
}

//ctor
MyType(Test _testStr = ??? )
{
}
```

This may be a stupid question but i cant seem to figure it out.

Regards!

Comment: did you try `Test _testStr = { x, y }` ?

Comment: Well yes. I considered that you wanted to set a default value for `_testStr`. What exactly is it, that you want to do?

Comment: I have a method called MyType and i want that in her constructor i want to send as param that struct called Test, but i want it to have a default value when i give it as param

Comment: You want `_testStr` to have a default argument? Well then do what @theCNG27 said. You of course will then need to do something with `_testStr`.

Comment: Structs are initializable like this:         Test _testStr = {.x = 100, .y = 100} , so maybe that's what you want.

Comment: @Andariel not all structs (and not ll classes), but this one is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer was:

```
Test _testStr = {.x = 100, .y = 100}
```